# Print output in php using Sql queries

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on PHP where i want to fetch the count of a particular column 'uid' from users table. The output window is not displaying anything. following is the code. Can anybody, help me in rectifying this code.

```
    <?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("rth_db");
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(uid) AS Total FROM users", $link);
    $number = mysql_fetch_array($data);
    echo $number;
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should address your data differently

```
echo $number["Total"];
```

Also, mysql is deprecated, have a look at PDO.
This also is better for security and so on. You can check the PHP.NET page for more info on this

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
echo $number;
```

to

```
print_r($number);
```

OR

```
echo $number['Total'];
```

Because `$number` is `array` not `string`.

Comment: @Tikkes We can use in this way also...:)

Answer (score 1):

try using this :

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("rth_db");
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(uid) AS Total FROM users", $link);
    $number = mysql_fetch_array($data);
    echo $number['total'];
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

i have just edited one line if u notice...hope this works :)

Answer (score 0):

u can also use

```
var_dump($number);
```